# Does anyone have a solution to 10.04 LTS not recognizing blank CD/DVDs?

Tags: 10.04, cd, dvd, burning

After I upgraded to the latest version, and I'm fully up to date, I can no longer burn CDs or DVDs, the OS simply will not recognize any blank media. Has anyone else been experiencing this and if so have you found a solution?

Comment: I had this problem too.

Answer (score 2):

There has been a documented issue with this on the previous [version](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/559387) of ubuntu. If you had upgraded your system the problem may still be persistent, simply due to the nature of the upgrade.

I would recommend a clean install.

Comment: I did a clean install and I had this problem too.

Comment: Ditto. I did a clean install and I still can't burn.

Answer (score 1):

Does it detect other CD/DVD media? if not then problem lies with CD/DVD drive - the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a wide spread issue - there are lots of forum threads (eg. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1544152, [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1539292](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1539292&page=2)) with similar issues.

It may help to update your kernel. Go to System -> Administration -> Update Manager and update all of your packages.

If there is no improvement, try installing the package `linux` (to install the latest kernel).

If there is still no improvement, you may need to use a ppa to install a newer kernel, that is not available from the repositories. I hear version '2.6.35' solves this issue with some people.

To install it, you need to add the repository: `ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa`
to your software sources. Then install: `linux-headers-2.6.35-14`, `linux-headers-2.6.35-14-generic` and `linux-image-2.6.35-14-generic`.

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same troubles and did a firmware update with the DVD/CD-Drive and everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

I always get this problem when the laser optics start to get dirty. It would read OK but not recognize blank media let alone try to burn them. A quick blast of air always fixed the problem. Get a can of compressed air and try it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not give any clue what hardware you have. I had that problem (and suspend/hibernate issue) on an old Dell Inspiron 8200 laptop. It had a hot swap drive bay that had a DVD drive in it. But apparently because it could be hot swapped, Linux kept polling for a floppy drive, resulting in log errors attempting to read fd0, lack of auto mounting USB or CD/DVD's, and failed to suspend or hibernate because it could not put udisks-deamon to sleep, which kept polling for the non-existing floppy.

So if you have no floppy and are getting any fd0 errors in dmesg or /var/log/messages similar to "end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0", either disable the floppy in your BIOS, or if that does not work:

Add following to **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf** (use sudo or gksu to run your editor):

**blacklist floppy**

Then do: **sudo update-initramfs -u**

Then reboot and see if USB and other removable media auto mounts when inserted.

Note that other partitions on internal drives are not auto mounted unless you make proper mount points (usually in /media unless you want it mounted elsewhere) and entries in /etc/fstab (preferably using UUID). Although, they will mount if you have permission and select them in Places.